# Is it possible to expose a header for specific bundle id?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm developing an objective-c SDK, and I'm using some class for ci tests.
I want to expose this class for testing within my ci-sample, which is not a part of the SDK project.

Is there any option to expose that header for specific bundle id?

Comment: Why not make a companion framework that contains the testing support for your SDK?

Comment: Actually, it can work. thanks